# Docker network conflict

Tags: docker, ip

I have an OpenProject container with an Nginx reverse proxy. I created a bridge network called *proxy* for them. I could call the OpenProject web page in the server domain but not in the domain of workstation. Maybe I am not to exact, sorry for it.
Well, the problem was Docker subnet IPs were in conflict with workstation's IPs. There was an overlap between them.
Therefore I created the daemon.json file in /etc/docker due to get different IPs. (I found this advise on the Internet.)
This is its content:

```
{
  "default-address-pools": [
    { "base": "10.0.2.0/18", "size": 24 }
  ]
}
```

I stopped container and remove all their Docker networks then I restarted Docker and I created the *proxy* network again but when I started again OpenProject container it stopped with this message:

> Error response from daemon: network 7371a6c729f3143ad73b81ac505a726bacd28147ba38b4e1ad084eed7eafa785 not found

So, now I do not know what to do with this error, please.

**UPDATE**

OpenProject docker-compose.yml file references these networks:

```
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
  proxy:
   external: true
```

and after I try to start it these networks are running:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME               DRIVER    SCOPE
c2712a814ce3   bridge             bridge    local
d1abf033bef1   compose_backend    bridge    local
e370558ece80   compose_default    bridge    local
916261afc4da   compose_frontend   bridge    local
24bb40d18154   host               host      local
75da711bd148   none               null      local
36832db7fcb2   proxy              bridge    local
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that if you removed and recreated all networks, your stopped container is now trying to attach itself to a network that does not exist any more, even if it has the same name.

You can see in your `docker network ls` the id of the proxy network: `36832db7fcb2`. Now inspect the configuration of the stopped container with `docker inspect [id of the container]`. If the `NetworkID` listed under Networks -> proxy is different that the id of your current proxy network, this is the case.

You can resolve this be first detaching the container from this nonexisting network:

`docker network disconnect proxy [container-id]`

and then restarting the container with

`docker start [container-id]`

Now, if it starts, you can reattach it to the network with:

`docker network connect proxy [container-id]`

Comment: Hi Teemu, Thank you but the OpenProject now with proxy network ut when I want to start Nginx container now it gives the same error but different id: Error response from daemon: network f45f27653a9fa0c9f6c6806edbf496a71d9d267f049adf8202e493223dabc6e0 not found
The proxy network is created by me and Open Project and Nginx container have its reference as external.

Comment: What does docker inspect say for the nginx container?

Comment: I can inspect only compose-web-1 which is one of the OpenProject containers. Its proxy network ID is Ok . I cannot start Nginx due to the mentioned error. I do not understand it, as if the proxy network Id is stuck somewhere.

Comment: Now I created another bridge network myproxy.  OpenProject containers is running with it but when I want to start nginx container it gives this message: service "nginx" refers to undefined network myproxy: invalid compose project

Comment: It is working. The docker-compose.yml file was invalid. networks section was misdefined. Thank you.